# PytorchでのTransformerの実装に関して

Tags: python, 深層学習, pytorch

こんにちは
TransformerをPytorchを利用して実装しようとしているのですが、
おもったような結果になりません。
以下が、訓練のコード、モデル定義のコード、データローダと出力結果のファイルです。

訓練のコード
**Train.py**

```
from transformer import EncoderDecoder, Encoder, LayerNorm, EncoderLayer, Decoder, DecoderLayer, MultiHeadedAttention, PositionwiseFeedForward, Embeddings, PositionalEncoding, Generator
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math, copy, time
from torch.autograd import Variable
import argparse
from loader import Seq2seqDataset
from torchtext import data
import sentencepiece as spm

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.load("./bert-wiki-ja/wiki-ja.model")

def subsequent_mask(size):
    "Mask out subsequent positions."
    attn_shape = (1, size, size)
    subsequent_mask = np.triu(np.ones(attn_shape), k=1).astype('uint8')
    return torch.from_numpy(subsequent_mask) == 0

def make_model(src_vocab, tgt_vocab, N=6, 
               d_model=516, d_ff=2048, h=8, dropout=0.1):
    "Helper: Construct a model from hyperparameters."
    c = copy.deepcopy
    attn = MultiHeadedAttention(h, d_model)
    ff = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff, dropout)
    position = PositionalEncoding(d_model, dropout)
    model = EncoderDecoder(
        Encoder(EncoderLayer(d_model, c(attn), c(ff), dropout), N),
        Decoder(DecoderLayer(d_model, c(attn), c(attn), 
                             c(ff), dropout), N),
        nn.Sequential(Embeddings(d_model, src_vocab), c(position)),
        nn.Sequential(Embeddings(d_model, tgt_vocab), c(position)),
        Generator(d_model, tgt_vocab))

    # This was important from their code. 
    # Initialize parameters with Glorot / fan_avg.
    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform(p)
    return model

def data_load(maxlen, source_size, batch_size):
    data_set = Seq2seqDataset(maxlen=maxlen)
    data_num = len(data_set)
    train_ratio = int(data_num*0.8)
    eval_ratio = int(data_num*0.1)
    test_ratio = int(data_num*0.1)
    res = int(data_num - (train_ratio + eval_ratio + test_ratio))
    train_ratio += res
    ratio=[train_ratio, eval_ratio, test_ratio]
    train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data_set, ratio)
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    del(train_dataset)
    del(data_set)
    return dataloader, val_dataloader

def make_std_mask(tgt, pad):
    tgt_mask = (tgt != pad).unsqueeze(-2)
    tgt_mask = tgt_mask & Variable(subsequent_mask(tgt.size(-1)).type_as(tgt_mask.data))
    return tgt_mask

def run_epoch(data_iter, model, loss_compute):
    "Standard Training and Logging Function"
    start = time.time()
    total_tokens = 0
    total_loss = 0
    tokens = 0
    pad = 0
    model = model.train()
    print(len(data_iter))
    for i, data in enumerate(data_iter):
        model = model.cuda() 
        src, trg = data[0], data[1]
        src, trg = src.cuda(), trg.cuda()
        src_mask = (src != pad).unsqueeze(-2)
        trg = trg[:, :-1]
        trg_y = trg[:, 1:]
        trg_mask = make_std_mask(trg, pad)
        ntokens = (trg_y != pad).data.sum()
        out = model.forward(src, trg, 
                            src_mask, trg_mask)
        loss = loss_compute(out, trg_y, ntokens)
        total_loss += loss
        total_tokens += ntokens
        tokens += ntokens
        if i % 50 == 1:
            elapsed = time.time() - start
            print("Epoch Step: %d Loss: %f Tokens per Sec: %f" %
                    (i, loss / ntokens, tokens / elapsed))
            start = time.time()
            tokens = 0
    torch.save({
                'model': model.state_dict()
                }, "./model_log/transformer.pt")
    return total_loss / total_tokens

global max_src_in_batch, max_tgt_in_batch
def batch_size_fn(new, count, sofar):
    "Keep augmenting batch and calculate total number of tokens + padding."
    global max_src_in_batch, max_tgt_in_batch
    if count == 1:
        max_src_in_batch = 0
        max_tgt_in_batch = 0
    max_src_in_batch = max(max_src_in_batch,  len(new.src))
    max_tgt_in_batch = max(max_tgt_in_batch,  len(new.trg) + 2)
    src_elements = count * max_src_in_batch
    tgt_elements = count * max_tgt_in_batch
    return max(src_elements, tgt_elements)



def get_std_opt(model):
    return NoamOpt(model.src_embed[0].d_model, 2, 4000,
            torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9))

def greedy_decode(model, data_iter, maxlen, start_symbol):
    print("------start_val-----")
    model = model.eval()
    all_y = []
    for i, data in enumerate(data_iter):
        aa = data[0]
        if i/50 == 0:
            print(str(i) + "/" + str(len(data_iter)))
        c = 0
        for src in aa:
            src = src.cuda()
            src = src.unsqueeze(0)
            src_mask = Variable(torch.ones(1,1,20))
            src_mask = src_mask.cuda()
            ys = torch.ones(1, 1).fill_(start_symbol).type_as(src.data)
            memory = model.encode(src, src_mask)
            for i in range(maxlen-1):
                out = model.decode(memory, src_mask, 
                                Variable(ys), 
                                Variable(subsequent_mask(ys.size(1)).type_as(src.data)))
                prob = model.generator(out[:, -1])
                _, next_word = torch.max(prob, dim = 1)
                next_word = next_word.data[0]
                ys = torch.cat([ys, 
                                torch.ones(1, 1).type_as(src.data).fill_(next_word)], dim=1)
            all_y.append(ys)
            if c == 1:
                break
            c = c+1
        break
    return all_y


class NoamOpt:
    "Optim wrapper that implements rate."
    def __init__(self, model_size, factor, warmup, optimizer):
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self._step = 0
        self.warmup = warmup
        self.factor = factor
        self.model_size = model_size
        self._rate = 0

    def step(self):
        "Update parameters and rate"
        self._step += 1
        rate = self.rate()
        for p in self.optimizer.param_groups:
            p['lr'] = rate
        self._rate = rate
        self.optimizer.step()

    def rate(self, step = None):
        "Implement `lrate` above"
        if step is None:
            step = self._step
        return self.factor * \
            (self.model_size ** (-0.5) *
            min(step ** (-0.5), step * self.warmup ** (-1.5)))

class LabelSmoothing(nn.Module):
    "Implement label smoothing."
    def __init__(self, size, padding_idx, smoothing=0.0):
        super(LabelSmoothing, self).__init__()
        self.criterion = nn.KLDivLoss(size_average=False)
        self.padding_idx = padding_idx
        self.confidence = 1.0 - smoothing
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.size = size
        self.true_dist = None

    def forward(self, x, target):
        assert x.size(1) == self.size
        true_dist = x.data.clone()
        true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (self.size - 2))
        true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), self.confidence)
        true_dist[:, self.padding_idx] = 0
        mask = torch.nonzero(target.data == self.padding_idx)
        if mask.dim() > 0:
            true_dist.index_fill_(0, mask.squeeze(), 0.0)
        self.true_dist = true_dist
        return self.criterion(x, Variable(true_dist, requires_grad=False))

class SimpleLossCompute:
    "A simple loss compute and train function."
    def __init__(self, generator, criterion, opt=None):
        self.generator = generator
        self.criterion = criterion
        self.opt = opt

    def __call__(self, x, y, norm):
        x = self.generator(x)
        x = x[:,1:]
        loss = self.criterion(x.contiguous().view(-1, x.size(-1)), 
                              y.contiguous().view(-1)) / norm
        loss.backward()
        if self.opt is not None:
            self.opt.step()
            self.opt.optimizer.zero_grad()
        return loss.data * norm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_size = 32000
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse training parameters')
    parser.add_argument('--do_train', type=str, default='False',
                        help='')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=128,
                        help='number of examples in a batch')
    parser.add_argument('--maxlen', type=int, default=20,
                        help='Sequences will be padded or truncated to this size.')    
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10,
                        help='the number of epochs to train')   
    args = parser.parse_args()             
    model = make_model(source_size, source_size)
    data_iter, val_data_iter = data_load(args.maxlen, source_size, args.batch_size)

    model = model.train()
    model = model.cuda()

    V=32000
    criterion = LabelSmoothing(size=V, padding_idx=sp.PieceToId("[PAD]"), smoothing=0.0)
    model_opt = NoamOpt(model.src_embed[0].d_model, 1, 400,
        torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0., betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9))

    if args.do_train == "True":
        for epoch in range(args.epochs):
            run_epoch(data_iter, model, SimpleLossCompute(model.generator, criterion, model_opt))
    else:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./model_log/transformer.pt")["model"])
    start_symbol = sp.PieceToId("<s>")
    result = greedy_decode(model, val_data_iter, args.maxlen, start_symbol)
    print("------end_val------")
    with open("./log.txt", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for i in  result:
            for j in i:
                for tok in j:
                    f.write(sp.IdToPiece(int(tok)))
                f.write("\n")
```

モデル定義のコード
**transformer.py**

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math, copy, time
from torch.autograd import Variable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
seaborn.set_context(context="talk")

class EncoderDecoder(nn.Module):
    """
    A standard Encoder-Decoder architecture. Base for this and many 
    other models.
    """
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, src_embed, tgt_embed, generator):
        super(EncoderDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.src_embed = src_embed
        self.tgt_embed = tgt_embed
        self.generator = generator

    def forward(self, src, tgt, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        "Take in and process masked src and target sequences."
        return self.decode(self.encode(src, src_mask), src_mask,
                            tgt, tgt_mask)

    def encode(self, src, src_mask):
        return self.encoder(self.src_embed(src), src_mask)

    def decode(self, memory, src_mask, tgt, tgt_mask):
        return self.decoder(self.tgt_embed(tgt), memory, src_mask, tgt_mask)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    "Define standard linear + softmax generation step."
    def __init__(self, d_model, vocab):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab)

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.log_softmax(self.proj(x), dim=-1)

def clones(module, N):
    "Produce N identical layers."
    return nn.ModuleList([copy.deepcopy(module) for _ in range(N)])

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    "Core encoder is a stack of N layers"
    def __init__(self, layer, N):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = clones(layer, N)
        self.norm = LayerNorm(layer.size)

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        "Pass the input (and mask) through each layer in turn."
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class LayerNorm(nn.Module):
    "Construct a layernorm module (See citation for details)."
    def __init__(self, features, eps=1e-6):
        super(LayerNorm, self).__init__()
        self.a_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(features))
        self.b_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(features))
        self.eps = eps

    def forward(self, x):
        mean = x.mean(-1, keepdim=True)
        std = x.std(-1, keepdim=True)
        return self.a_2 * (x - mean) / (std + self.eps) + self.b_2

class SublayerConnection(nn.Module):
    """
    A residual connection followed by a layer norm.
    Note for code simplicity the norm is first as opposed to last.
    """
    def __init__(self, size, dropout):
        super(SublayerConnection, self).__init__()
        self.norm = LayerNorm(size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x, sublayer):
        "Apply residual connection to any sublayer with the same size."
        return x + self.dropout(sublayer(self.norm(x)))

class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    "Encoder is made up of self-attn and feed forward (defined below)"
    def __init__(self, size, self_attn, feed_forward, dropout):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = self_attn
        self.feed_forward = feed_forward
        self.sublayer = clones(SublayerConnection(size, dropout), 2)
        self.size = size

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        "Follow Figure 1 (left) for connections."
        x = self.sublayer[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attn(x, x, x, mask))
        return self.sublayer[1](x, self.feed_forward)

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    "Generic N layer decoder with masking."
    def __init__(self, layer, N):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = clones(layer, N)
        self.norm = LayerNorm(layer.size)

    def forward(self, x, memory, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, memory, src_mask, tgt_mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class DecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    "Decoder is made of self-attn, src-attn, and feed forward (defined below)"
    def __init__(self, size, self_attn, src_attn, feed_forward, dropout):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.size = size
        self.self_attn = self_attn
        self.src_attn = src_attn
        self.feed_forward = feed_forward
        self.sublayer = clones(SublayerConnection(size, dropout), 3)

    def forward(self, x, memory, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        "Follow Figure 1 (right) for connections."
        m = memory
        x = self.sublayer[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attn(x, x, x, tgt_mask))
        x = self.sublayer[1](x, lambda x: self.src_attn(x, m, m, src_mask))
        return self.sublayer[2](x, self.feed_forward)



def attention(query, key, value, mask=None, dropout=None):
    "Compute 'Scaled Dot Product Attention'"
    d_k = query.size(-1)
    scores = torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(-2, -1)) \
             / math.sqrt(d_k)
    if mask is not None:
        scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)
    p_attn = F.softmax(scores, dim = -1)
    if dropout is not None:
        p_attn = dropout(p_attn)
    return torch.matmul(p_attn, value), p_attn

class MultiHeadedAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h, d_model, dropout=0.1):
        "Take in model size and number of heads."
        super(MultiHeadedAttention, self).__init__()
        assert d_model % h == 0
        # We assume d_v always equals d_k
        self.d_k = d_model // h
        self.h = h
        self.linears = clones(nn.Linear(d_model, d_model), 4)
        self.attn = None
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    def forward(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        "Implements Figure 2"
        if mask is not None:
            # Same mask applied to all h heads.
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1)
        nbatches = query.size(0)

        # 1) Do all the linear projections in batch from d_model => h x d_k 
        query, key, value = \
            [l(x).view(nbatches, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
             for l, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))]

        # 2) Apply attention on all the projected vectors in batch. 
        x, self.attn = attention(query, key, value, mask=mask, 
                                 dropout=self.dropout)

        # 3) "Concat" using a view and apply a final linear. 
        x = x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous() \
             .view(nbatches, -1, self.h * self.d_k)
        return self.linears[-1](x)

class PositionwiseFeedForward(nn.Module):
    "Implements FFN equation."
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(PositionwiseFeedForward, self).__init__()
        self.w_1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.w_2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.w_2(self.dropout(F.relu(self.w_1(x))))

class Embeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, vocab):
        super(Embeddings, self).__init__()
        self.lut = nn.Embedding(vocab, d_model)
        self.d_model = d_model

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.lut(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    "Implement the PE function."
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

        # Compute the positional encodings once in log space.
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0.0, max_len).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0.0, d_model, 2) * (-(math.log(10000.0) / d_model)))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + Variable(self.pe[:, :x.size(1)], 
                         requires_grad=False)
        return self.dropout(x)

def make_model(src_vocab, tgt_vocab, N=6, 
               d_model=512, d_ff=2048, h=8, dropout=0.1):
    "Helper: Construct a model from hyperparameters."
    c = copy.deepcopy
    attn = MultiHeadedAttention(h, d_model)
    ff = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff, dropout)
    position = PositionalEncoding(d_model, dropout)
    model = EncoderDecoder(
        Encoder(EncoderLayer(d_model, c(attn), c(ff), dropout), N),
        Decoder(DecoderLayer(d_model, c(attn), c(attn), 
                             c(ff), dropout), N),
        nn.Sequential(Embeddings(d_model, src_vocab), c(position)),
        nn.Sequential(Embeddings(d_model, tgt_vocab), c(position)),
        Generator(d_model, tgt_vocab))

    # This was important from their code. 
    # Initialize parameters with Glorot / fan_avg.
    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform(p)
    return model
```

データローダ
**loader.py**

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import csv
import sentencepiece as spm

class Seq2seqDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
        self.sp.load("./bert-wiki-ja/wiki-ja.model")
        self.maxlen = maxlen


        with open('./data/parallel_data.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            csv_file = csv.reader(f)
            read_data = [row for row in csv_file]
        self.data_num = len(read_data) - 1
        jp_data = []
        es_data = []
        for i in range(1, self.data_num):    
            jp_data.append(read_data[i][1:2])
            es_data.append(read_data[i][2:3])


        self.en_data_idx = np.zeros((len(jp_data), maxlen))
        self.de_data_idx = np.zeros((len(es_data), maxlen+1))

        for i,sentence in enumerate(jp_data):
            for j,idx in enumerate(self.sp.EncodeAsIds(sentence[0])[1:]):
                self.en_data_idx[i][j] = idx
                if j == maxlen-1:
                    break
            if j < maxlen-1:
                self.en_data_idx[i][j:] = self.sp.PieceToId("[PAD]")
        for i,sentence in enumerate(es_data):
            self.de_data_idx[i][0] = self.sp.PieceToId("<s>")
            for j,idx in enumerate(self.sp.EncodeAsIds(sentence[0])[1:]):
                self.de_data_idx[i][j+1] = idx
                if j+1 == maxlen:
                    break
            if j+1 < maxlen:
                self.de_data_idx[i][j+1:] = self.sp.PieceToId("[PAD]")

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_num

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        en_data = torch.tensor(self.en_data_idx[idx-1][:], dtype=torch.long)
        de_data = torch.tensor(self.de_data_idx[idx-1][:], dtype=torch.long)
        target = torch.zeros((self.maxlen+1), dtype=torch.long)
        for i, data in enumerate(de_data[:]):
            target[i] = data
        target[i] = self.sp.PieceToId("</s>")

        return en_data, target
```

出力結果
**log.txt**

```
<s>ををををををををををををををををををを
<s>ををををををををををををををををををを
```

入力データにはhttp://www.jnlp.org/SNOW/T15のxlsxファイルをcsvに変換して使用しました。
難しい日本語をエンコーダへの入力に、優しい日本語をデコーダへの入力にしています。
形態素解析に用いたsentencepieceモデルはbertの事前学習に利用されたhttps://yoheikikuta.github.io/bert-japanese/を利用しています。
transformerのモデルはhttp://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.htmlを参考にほぼ丸写しで実装しています。
ハイパーパラメータはTrain.pyを引数なし（ただし--do_train="True"）で実行した場合で訓練しました。

また過学習を疑い、件数が20倍のデータ（公開できません）で学習したり、モデルの層を減らしたりもしてみたのですがほとんど同じ結果でした。

原因はどこにあるのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに結果は正しくなかったとしてもなにかしらランダムに単語が出力されることを想定していました